# Where have the 9.10 CD images gone?

Tags: release-management

My installation scripts rely on downloading Karmic, but they seem to have disappeared.  They were there a couple of weeks ago I believe.
Any advice would be very welcome.

Sorry more info, Using Mint 8 that uses Ubuntu9.10, but the Karmic repository appears to have vanished.

Comment: Mint is not supported here.  Please read the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) to learn what is or is not allowed here on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: If you wanted to be generous, you can read this as really just asking where the Karmic images went.   The Mint part could be removed without affecting any potential answer.

Answer (score 5):

The Karmic images are now in the [old-releases folder](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) of ubuntu.com

Since Karmic is end-of-life you will need to change your scripts to find the old[-releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/) repository

This is described further in the [community EOL wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, now I fully understand what end of life means. cheers

Comment: I have installed my software from the old-releases repository and upgraded it fine.  So I have just tried to upgrade from a release from the archive repository using the sources.list file modified and pointing to the old-release repository and it fails.  It can't find python python configobj  It seems as though the two repositories are different.  Can anyone confirm please.

Comment: Are you attempting to upgrade from 9.10 to 10.04?  Or are you just upgrading existing karmic packages?  Either way, please create a new question giving details of your existing sources.list together with the exact error message you are reporting.